# PHP looping array to get combined rows of items

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I need to turn this array:

```
$data = array(array('a', 'b'), array('1','2'), array('hi','bye'));
```

Into this one:

```
$final = array (array ('a', '1', 'hi'), array ('b','2','bye'));
```

How do I loop `$data` to get `$final`? I've been looping for hours and I cannot get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/array_map) in an interesting way to do this:

```
$data = array(array('a', 'b'), array('1','2'), array('hi','bye'));
array_unshift($data, null); /* or use the array union operator: array(null) + $data */
$result = call_user_func_array('array_map', $data);
print_r($result);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => 1
            [2] => hi
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => b
            [1] => 2
            [2] => bye
        )

)
```

Hope this helps :)

**Edit**

If you're interested in a breakdown of what is happening here, I've written a [short blog post here](http://darraghenright.tumblr.com/post/26594280324/vertically-slice-rotate-a-multidimensional-php-array)

Basically, if you pass `null` as the first argument to `array_map`, you can then pass an arbitrary number of arrays to it - the function does all the rotating for you. Useful!

If you have an array of arrays (as you do) then you need some help with `call_user_func_array` to "unpack" the arrays.

Comment: No problem :) It's a pretty useful (and sort of unusual) use case for `array_map` - if you go to its manual page (http://ie1.php.net/array_map) it discusses it under Example #4